# Python zip function in Matlab

Tags: python, list, matlab

I have some Python code that I would like to run in Matlab. Suppose you have two lists of the same length:

```
    x = [0, 2, 2, 5, 8, 10]
    y = [0,2, 4, 7, 3, 3]

    P = np.copy(y)
    P.sort()
    P = np.unique(P, axis=0) # P = [0 2 3 4 7]  Takes the list y, sorts it and removes repeated elements

    s = list(zip(x,y))  #match list x with y: s = [(0, 0), (2, 2), (2, 4), (5, 7), (8, 3), (10, 3)]

    for y_1,y_2 in zip(P,P[1:]):  # runs over (0, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 7)
        for v_1,v_2 in zip(s, s[1:]):
                -- process --
```

Where in this case:

```
list(zip(s, s[1:])) = [((0, 0), (2, 2)), ((2, 2), (2, 4)), ((2, 4), (5, 7)), ((5, 7), (8, 3)), ((8, 3), (10, 3))]
```

I would like to translate this in Matlab but I don't know how to replicate the `zip` function. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Matlab likes to use aligned arrays, instead of the small struct-like things or tuples that Python produces using zip. And then you try to do "vectorized" operations instead of using loops. So the right data structure for this depends entirely on what you want to do _inside_ that loop with the "-- process --" stuff. What's that going to do?

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB doesn’t have a `zip`, but you can accomplish the same thing in various ways. I think that the simplest translation of

```py
for y_1,y_2 in zip(P,P[1:]):
   ...
```

is

```matlab
for ii = 1:numel(P)-1
   y_1 = P(ii);
   y_2 = P(ii+1);
   ...
```

And in general, iterating over `zip(x,y)` is accomplished by iterating over indices `1:numel(x)`, then using the loop index to index into the arrays `x` and `y`.

Comment: Matlab does have a `zip` function. It creates `.zip` files. ;) https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zip.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of Python's `zip` function in Matlab.

```matlab
function out = zip(varargin)
% Emulate Python's zip() function.
%
% Don't actually use this! It will be slow. Matlab code works differently.
args = varargin;
nArgs = numel(args);
n = numel(args{1});
out = cell(1, n);
for i = 1:n
    blah = cell(1, nArgs);
    for j = 1:nArgs
        if iscell(args{j})
            blah(j) = args{j}(i);
        else
            blah{j} = args{j}(i);
        end
    end
    out{i} = blah;
end
end
```

But don't use it; the performance will be lousy. In Matlab, you want to keep things in parallel primitive arrays instead, and use vectorized operations on those. Or, if you have to, iterate over array indexes.

Comment: Interesting idea. MATLAB syntax still doesn’t allow doing `for y_1,y_2 in zip(P,P[1:])`, but this brings us a little closer.

Comment: Oooh, a parallel `for` loop syntax in Matlab is interesting! `x = 1:10; y = x*2; z  =y*2; for x_i, y_i, z_i = x, y, z;  do_something(x_i, y_i, z_i); end`. Come drop by https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1450984-what-should-go-in-a-next-generation-matlab-x and request it for MATLAB X. ;)

Comment: My favorite way of doing this now is to loop through the rows or columns of a 2-D cell array: `c = num2cell(magic(4)); for col = c; [x,y,z,q] = col{:}; end`.

Answer (score 0):

A `zip` list comprehension can be partially recreated via

```matlab
ls0 = [1 2];
ls1 = [3 4];

g = [ls0; ls1]';
cellfun(@(x)[x(1)*0, x(2) + 1], {g(1,:), g(2,:)}, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

```
ans =

  1×2 cell array

    {[0 4]}    {[0 5]}
```

or, as a 1-liner (returning 2x2 matrix instead)

```matlab
table2array(rowfun(@(x)[x(1)*0, x(2) + 1], table([ls0; ls1]')))
```

which in Python is

```py
ls0, ls1 = [1, 2], [3, 4]
[(a*0, b + 1) for a, b in zip(ls0, ls1)]
```

```
[(0, 4), (0, 5)]
```

They're fair options for when inputs are small. If speed/memory is of concern, best to instead focus on MATLAB-efficient commands (beware of copies).

One could generalize this to any number of lists and comprehension logic (arbitrary function instead of `*0`) and introduce conditionals; I've done this for `dictionary` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76812753/10133797).

Alternatives in other answers, and I especially like @AndrewJanke's comment (plain for-loop)

```matlab
c = num2cell([ls0; ls1]');
for col = c
    [a, b] = col{:};
    disp([a, b])
end
```

```
     1     2

     3     4
```